# URL rewrite PHP & pulls data from a MySql DB

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have a site tha is written in PHP and pulls data from a MySql DB. The site 
utilises query strings and I would like to map the query generated pages to the 
more search engine friendly page titles. For example I would like to acheive to 
the following mappings:

```
content.php?id=1 to map to /aboutus 
content.php?id=2 to map to /contactus
content.php?id=3 to map to /newfiles
```

how can i do this, in a more simple way. is that simply changing .htaccess 
file, or is that related to rewrite mapping function. pls can you give me hint 
and exact example would be great. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a field called permalink (or similar) in your database. e.g.

```
id | permalink | content |
1  | aboutus   | bra bra |
2  | contactus | bra bra |
```

Then use this in your .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ content.php?permalink=$1 [L]
```

What above .htaccess does is recognize your url in first level and pass it to url variable.
e.g. when user type

```
yoursite.com/aboutus/
```

It will actually request to

```
yoursite.com/content.php?permalink=aboutus
```

(but user don't see it)

then you use $_GET['permalink'] to match your database and get content display on the screen.