# Use data from database in url with htaccess

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I have a custom link stored in a MySQL database and I want that link use instead of the default get-link with htaccess.

Example: If a visitor will read a blog, the url is www.domain.com/blog.php?post_link=2017-07-05/First-Post

Is there any way to use the post_link from the database instead the url now?
I've read something about it here: [SO Item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12135414/url-rewrite-php-pulls-data-from-a-mysql-db), but that don't work...

Please help!

---

Before: www.domain.com/blog.php?post_link=2017-07-05/First-Post

After: www.domain.com/blog/2017-07-05/First-Post

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNAOh.png)

[This is my code in blog.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67dB7.png)

PS: It is SEO only..

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)$ /blog.php?post_link=$1&First-Post=$2 [NC,QSA]
```

I have not tested it yet i hope it will work. and give you the desired results.

[here is the answer in details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709634/convert-original-url-to-friendly-url)